# Select sum of hours grouped by a day first and then by a week

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle-apex

in Oracle ApEx I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE  "ATTENDANCE_HOURS" 
   ("ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PERSON_ID" NUMBER, 
    "PROJECT_ID" NUMBER, 
    "FROM_X" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TO_X" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NOTE" VARCHAR2(300), 
    "APPROVED" NUMBER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "APPROVAL_NOTE" VARCHAR2(300), 
    "DAY" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "CHECK_TIMES" CHECK (TO_CHAR(TO_X, 'HH24MI') > TO_CHAR(FROM_X, 'HH24MI')) ENABLE, 
 CONSTRAINT "ATTENDANCE_HOURS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )
```

Note: I cannot change the table. Just nope. 
I need to, for each person, select how many hours a week they worked. I already have a selection for How many hours a day (thanks StackOverflow) that looks like this:

```
select 
    (MAX("TO_X") - MIN("FROM_X"))*24 - 
    (max(case when PROJECT_ID = 21 then to_x else to_date('01012000','DDMMYYYY') end) -
    max(case when PROJECT_ID = 21 then from_x else to_date('01012000','DDMMYYYY')       end))*24 AS TIME_SPENT
// project id = 21 is break
from #OWNER#.ATTENDANCE_HOURS
GROUP BY DAY
```

What occured to me, was to group the entries next by week number and put the whole thing into SUM(), but well, it doesn't work and it says that: not a single-group group function.
Or maybe I should start playing with views?

Comment: It's not clear what the columns mean. What defines an hour worked? Is there one row per day per person per project? Why are you special casing project ID 21?

Comment: @Ben b/c project 21 is break that doesn't count into time spent working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total hours for each person in a week would look something like this:

```
select person_id, to_char(day, 'YYYY-WW') as week,
       sum(to_x - from_x) as hours_worked
from #OWNER#.ATTENDANCE_HOURS
group by person_id, to_char(day, 'YYYY-WW')
order by person_id, week;
```

I have no idea what the extra logic is on the project id.  Your question doesn't explain it, so I removed it as unnecessary for calculating the sum of the hours.  You can add it back in, if it is important.

Comment: project id is there to distinguish what project the people worked on and there is one special project - break, that doesn't get count into hours spent working.

Comment: +1 to this answer. But be always carefull with the usage of weeks especially for beninning and end of year. For example you expect to_char(day, 'YYYY-WW') for the first of January 2015 like 2015-01, but the result can be 2015-52 because 1st f january belongs to the last week of the previous year.. A little bit confusing

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (untested)?

```
select person_id
     , trunc(from_x,'iw')                                     first_day_of_iso_week
     , sum((to_x - from_x) * 24)                              all_hours
     , sum((case project_id when 21 then to_x - from_x) * 24) break_hours
  from attendance_hours
 group by person_id        -- for each person
     , trunc(from_x,'iw')  -- for each ISO-week
```

Maybe you need an extra check constraint telling that the date part of to_x and from_x should be the same, check(trunc(from_x) = trunc(to_x))?

EDIT: I now see you have a superflous DAY column in your table as well. That's not a good idea as you now have to check (trunc(day) = trunc(to_x)) and trunc(day) = trunc(from_x). If you can, get rid of the day column: it is already included in your from_x and to_x columns.

Answer (score 0):

The following query gives you the sum of worked hours minus breaks for each person (provided project 21 means break and all others mean work):

```
select person_id, 
  sum(case when project_id = 21 then -1 else 1 end * (to_x - from_x)) * 24
from #OWNER#.ATTENDANCE_HOURS
group by person_id;
```

To get this per day can be quite complicated when work can be over midnight (or even span more than two days). As long as we assume that from_x and to_x are aways the same day, we get:

```
select person_id, trunc(from_x),
  sum(case when project_id = 21 then -1 else 1 end * (to_x - from_x)) * 24
from #OWNER#.ATTENDANCE_HOURS
group by person_id, trunc(from_x);
```

To get this per week would then be:

```
select person_id, trunc(from_x, 'IW'),
  sum(case when project_id = 21 then -1 else 1 end * (to_x - from_x)) * 24
from #OWNER#.ATTENDANCE_HOURS
group by person_id, trunc(from_x, 'IW');
```

EDIT: Oh, I just notice that I don't know enough of your data. Can a project attendance range from 9am to 11am when there is also a break from 10am to 10:15am? Then my queries work. Or would that be two project attendances then, one ranging from 9am to 10am and the other from 10:15am to 11am? Then you would need `sum(case when project_id = 21 then 0 else to_x - from_x end) * 24`instead.

EDIT: Okay, as you say in your comment that project_id = 21 cannot overlap, simply exclude it from your query:

```
select person_id, trunc(from_x, 'IW'), sum(to_x - from_x) * 24
from #OWNER#.ATTENDANCE_HOURS
where project_id <> 21 
group by person_id, trunc(from_x, 'IW');
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that! the hours spent on each project cannot overlap, so the second approach you described is correct. :)

Comment: Okay, I've edited my answer accordingly to give an even easier solution.